# File copy freezing with large network copies

Tags: samba

I'm using version 12.10. When I do large file copy from windows network share it always hangs the copy process. Rest of machine is fine, just the copy process is hung. I connect to the share by launching home folder then clicking on the network section. From there I can find my windows share. I'm finding this very annoying as I have over 2tb of data to migrate from my old windows environment to Ubuntu.

Comment: Samba? If so... samba is slow. Broadcasting to find computers on the network is never quick.... If this is a 1 time copy: yry with FTP or SSH.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like a case for rsync; there you can just resume the copy process in case it hangs or you have to reboot inbetween or whatever causes interruption.

```
rsync -avz -r --stats --progress --perms --links /windows/files/ /home/user/migrated/
```

The copy process itself is a bit slower, one should mention.

Further examples: http://rsync.samba.org/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Setting the `io` scheduling priority to 3 (idle) works for me. Issue `cp` command as:

```
ionice -c 3 cp fromFile toFile
```

So it means that the program could be waiting for too long and somehow exiting.